# ui binder pattern: initializing variables using generators

Tags: java, gwt, annotations, uibinder

I am trying to create a GWT generator that does the following:

```
public class MyPool {

    @InitializeThisVariable
    Element1  el1;

    @InitializeThisVariable
    Element2  el2;

    private static final ChildPool childPool = GWT
            .create(ChildPool.class);

    interface ChildPool extends Pool<MyPool>{}


    public MyPool(){

    }
}
```

I want the generator to initialize the annotated fields. After doing some research, I have found out that the only way to do this is to use the pattern used by ui-binder as above (I do not want to use Annotations Processors).

However I get the following error when compiling:

[ERROR] Line 16: Rebind result 'ChildPool' must be a class

Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your generator needs to return name if the generated class. Either that or you forgot the `<generate-with>` in your module.
Also, your code doesn't make use of the generated `Pool` instance.

Note however that generators are being deprecated in GWT 2.8, and you should really use other kind of code generators (be it annotation processors or something else). You shouldn't start writing new generators nowadays.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Would you having any other suggestion for this, other than annotation processors?